# How powerful is collective consciousness to the individual mind?

Tags: consciousness

What? How powerful is collective consciousness to the individual mind

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question does not appear to be about Buddhist philosophy, teaching, and practice, within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: hello, as written the question is too vague please add more context and we will reopen. Also as DD said, all questions should have some connection with this site's topic.

Answer (score 0):

The internet says:

> Collective consciousness, also known as collective conscience, is a
> sociological concept that refers to common ideas, attitudes, beliefs,
> and knowledge that are shared amongst a social group, organization, or
> society.

Buddhism says:

> 167. Follow not the vulgar way; live not in heedlessness; hold not false views; linger not long in worldly existence.
> 168. One who looks upon the world as a bubble and a mirage, him the King of Death sees not.
> 169. Come! Behold this world, which is like a decorated royal chariot. Here fools flounder, but the wise have no attachment to it.
>
> [Dhammapada](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.13.budd.html)

In Buddhism, there are [four/eight types of Enlightened Individuals](https://suttacentral.net/an8.59/en/sujato?lang=en&layout=linebyline&reference=none&notes=sidenotes&highlight=true&script=latin). The enlightened individuals do not follow the ways of the world. Particularly, there are times/occasions, where the collective attitude is false & immoral.